# "Замерзание" приложения при интенсивном emit

Tags: qt, qt5

Ситуация следующая:

Есть поток работающий с оборудованием.Он излучает достаточно часто (раз в 100, 50 мс) сигналы.

Приложение начинает "подвешиваться" и при окончании потока сигналов "развешиваться".

как правильно с этим (с подвешиванием) бороться?

Comment: со слотами поток соединен с QueuedConnection

Comment: Если основной поток принимает так часто сигнал, то естественно он будет тоже висеть.

Comment: и? как обработать такой поток не подвешивая приложение?

Comment: а что происходит в основном потоке в обработчике?

Comment: там все достаточно тривиально - вывод в лог, изменение состояния элементов на форме и т.п.

Comment: Подумайте. При QueuedConnection сигналы попадают в очередь обработки. Вы эту очередь засоряете.

Comment: ну дык для чего и пишется приложение - обработка данных от оборудования

Comment: Создайте еще один поток, в который будут приходить данные из потока, работающего с оборудованием, и критическую секцию, куда будете складывать данные. Поток с гуи будет отттуда забирать данные, когда захочет. Например так.

Comment: я сильно сомневаюсь, что есть люди, которые способны воспринимать информацию со скоростью 10-20 изменений в секунду. Но даже если и так - делайте так, что бы Ваши обработчики, которые работают в другом потоке были максимально легки. Логирование? не, им пусть занимается другой поток, Если пропустить одно обновление визуального состояние, то кто то заметит это? нет. Это как некоторые отрисовывают прогресс бар (а как мне кажется, это один с самых тяжелых контролов) на каждый шаг, который 10к-100к, а на экране это 200 пикслей максимум.

Comment: если что, то 20 раз в секунду на современном железе (последних лет 20) — это __очень__ не часто... так что стоит смотреть, где обработка тормозит...

Comment: каким образом посмотреть где тормозит?

Comment: "я сильно сомневаюсь, что есть люди, которые способны воспринимать информацию со скоростью 10-20 изменений в секунду. " да, но есть лог который оператор видит и имеет возможность проанализировать.